# Remove unwanted ios7 padding

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

iOS7 adds padding (64px) for the status bar. Therefore when using a Scrollview there is a big camp between the scrollview and the navigation bar. I tried:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Which does remove the unwanted padding - however the scrollview no longer scrolls.

Is there another way?

* update ********

I discovered a quick fix. I was lining up the scrollview and y origin= 64px in the storyboard instead of 0. I put my scroll view to 0px (the navigation bar then covered 64px of my scrollview) and when I ran it on the simulator it was aligned as originally intend ... a bit of a hack tho. I'm looking for a solid solution however.

Answer (score 10):

On your XIB/Storyboard for your view controller, make sure to uncheck the *Adjust Scroll View Insets*.  You may also need to uncheck *Under Top Bars* and *Under Bottom Bars*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it didnt work unfortunately. My little hack seems to be working at the moment

Comment: @Gman For me it didnt work when viewcontroller was used by page controller. So I changed that in page controller and it worked. Perhaps you have some external controller to screen that has that problem.

Comment: At first this didn't work for me neither, but later I found that if your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller/tabbar controller etc., you should uncheck this option for both your view controller and the wrapping one.